# Setting the gallery image in imageview

Tags: android, imageview, gallery

I am making the same activity as in android to set the wallpaper from the given gallery.

I have a gallery with 50 images when gallery stop scrolling a center image comes i want to show that image in imageview.

```
 g.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                final int arg2, long arg3)
        {

            imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[arg2]);  

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(WallpaperThemeChoose.this, "NOTHING",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

while scrolling the imageview set every image which are passing in gallery. So pause for sometime and then start i mean it stick for sometime while scrolling 
I don't want to show all images which are passing but only that image which comes to center when scrolling stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution by setting `g.setCallbackDuringFling(false);`